# Meaning of final for Scala constructor arguments and class/trait/object members

Tags: scala, constructor, final

What does `final` mean for Scala constructor arguments? I have this example:

```
class IntFinalTest(
    val intVal: Int,
    final val finalIntVal: Int,
    var intVar: Int,
    final var finalIntVar: Int) {
  //  intVal = 3 // error: reassignment to val
  //  finalIntVal = 3 // error: reassignment to val
  intVar = 3
  finalIntVar = 3
}

class ArrayFinalTest(
    val arrayVal: Array[Int],
    final val finalArrayVal: Array[Int],
    var arrayVar: Array[Int],
    final var finalArrayVar: Array[Int]) {
  arrayVal(0) = 3
  finalArrayVal(0) = 3
  arrayVar(0) = 3
  finalArrayVar(0) = 3
}
```

Judging by the compiler output (only the two marked lines result in an error), there is no difference between `final` and non-`final` `val`s and `var`s - is this correct? I have verified by running this example that all variables except for `intVal` and `finalIntVal` do get modified.

**Related question RQ1**: Does `final` have any significance in constructors of classes that are part of a hierarchy?

**Related question RQ2**: How do I create an immutable `Array[Int]` class member if it's part of constructor argument list?

Context: I use Scala 2.10.5 and only have a few months of experience with it.

Comment: I guess, `final` means that it cannot be overridden. (You know, `val arrayVal` creates a method that can be overridden.)

Comment: `Array[Int]` - is always mutable. Try `Seq[Int]`

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev This should be an answer.

Comment: I expanded the title to reflect that the same rules apply to class/trait/object members, as pointed out by Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `val` cannot be changed. A `val` *can* however be overridden, so even if you see a `val` somewhere, you can't know its value for sure. (In the general case, it is hard to tell whether a member is overridden or not. This is known as Class Hierarchy Analysis and is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.)

A `final val`, however cannot be changed and cannot be overridden, so you know that its value can never be different than the one it was initialized with. Constructor parameters which are annotated with `var` or `val` become members of the class, and so `final val` for a constructor parameter really means more or less the same thing as it does for a "normal" class/trait/object member.

Note that for (non-constructor) members declared *exactly* like this:

```
final val foo = e
```

i.e. with an *explicit* `final` modifier (even if the `val` were otherwise implicitly final, e.g. because it is inside a `final` class or inside an `object`), *without* a type annotation, and where `e` is a [*constant expression*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#constant-expressions), the declaration becomes a [*constant value declaration*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) which the Scala Language Specification guarantees to be optimized by the compiler.

Comment: Your final note was supposed to be my next question :) Thanks for the great answer!